# How to display data from database in sqlite in descending order?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have a Table in SQLite like the following

[image]

I want to display it in android listview based on the click column. That means in descending
order like 3,1,0 like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to query the database with a 'ORDER BY' clause. It would look something like this

```
Cursor cursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {"_id", "quote", "click"}, null, null, null, null, "click DESC");

cursor.moveToFirst(); // this will get the cursor ready to be used in an adapter

setListAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor, new String[] {"quote"}, new String[] {android.R.id.text1});
```

Assuming that the list was for the quotes and that you are working in a ListActivity

Answer (score 0):

Use a `SimpleCursorAdapter`, and when you create the query, specify "click DESC" as the sort order (last parameter of managedQuery()).

Comment: Is it possible throw sqlite qurey

Comment: Yes, it is. SQLite supports ordering.

Comment: can you please give me the query